# Deploying web application with fabric and supervisor - SIGHUP causes server to be terminated

Tags: python, deployment, fabric, supervisord

We are using supervisor to deploy a python web application. On deployment, the web application is installed on the server through buildout, and a script for running supervisor is created using collective.recipe.supervisor . This script is called at the end of the deployment process by a fabric script. The problem is that when the deployment script is finished, a SIGHUP signal is sent to the process, which causes supervisor to restart (as per this line: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/supervisord.py#L300 ), but due to some reason, the web app is not restarted after it is terminated. There is no log output after the following:

```
2012-10-24 15:23:51,510 WARN received SIGHUP indicating restart request
2012-10-24 15:23:51,511 INFO waiting for app-server to die
2012-10-24 15:23:54,650 INFO waiting for app-server to die
2012-10-24 15:23:57,653 INFO waiting for app-server to die
2012-10-24 15:24:00,657 INFO waiting for app-server to die
2012-10-24 15:24:01,658 WARN killing 'app-server' (28981) with SIGKILL
2012-10-24 15:24:01,659 INFO stopped: app-server (terminated by SIGKILL)
```

So I have two questions. The first one is, does anyone know why supervisor restarts on SIGHUP? I couldn't find any explanation for this, and there are no command line options that would turn this behavior off. The second question is, how can we fix the problem we are facing? We tried starting supervisor with a nohup, but the SIGHUP is still received. The weird thing is that this doesn't happen when I log on to the server, start supervisor by hand, and log out.

Here is the supervisor script generated by buildout:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
'/home/username/.buildout/eggs/supervisor-3.0b1-py2.6.egg',
'/home/username/.buildout/eggs/meld3-0.6.9-py2.6.egg',
'/home/username/.buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.30-py2.6.egg',
]


import sys; sys.argv.extend(["-c","/home/username/app_directory/parts/supervisor/supervisord.conf"])

import supervisor.supervisord

if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.exit(supervisor.supervisord.main())
```

And here is the configuration file for supervisor, also generated by buildout:

```
[supervisord]
childlogdir = /home/username/app_directory/var/log
logfile = /home/username/app_directory/var/log/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
logfile_backups = 10
loglevel = info
pidfile = /home/username/app_directory/var/supervisord.pid
umask = 022
nodaemon = false
nocleanup = false

[unix_http_server]
file = /home/username/app_directory/supervisor.sock
username = username
password = apasswd
chmod = 0700

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///home/username/app_directory/supervisor.sock
username = username
password = apasswd

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:app-server]
command = /home/username/app_directory/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:wsgi
process_name = app-server
directory = /home/username/app_directory/bin
priority = 50
redirect_stderr = false
directory = /home/username/app_directory
```

We don't want to install a patched version of supervisor before really understanding the problem, so any information would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Restarting or reloading on `SIGHUP` is common practice in system programming for linux. The question is why you are getting `SIGHUP` after deployment ends. Since supervisor daemonize itself correctly (because you can start it and log out and it will work), the reload signal may be sent to supervisor by building bot, indicating that webapp need to be restarted, because code has changed.

So supervisor initiates app shutdown, in order to start app with new code. But app would not stop in given timeout, and supervisor decides that app hang and kill it with `SIGKILL`.

To solve a problem, you need teach the app to shutdown when supervisor ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

The supervisord docs clearly state that sending SIGHUP to a supervisord process will "stop all processes, reload the configuration from the first config file it finds, and restart all processes".

ref - http://supervisord.org/running.html#signal-handlers

Perhaps your process is misbehaving; it looks like supervisor made several attempts to nicely shut it down, but then decided it needed a hard kill:

```
process.py:560
# kill processes which are taking too long to stop with a final
# sigkill.  if this doesn't kill it, the process will be stuck
# in the STOPPING state forever.
self.config.options.logger.warn(
    killing %r (%s) with SIGKILL' % (self.config.name, self.pid))
self.kill(signal.SIGKILL)
```

Maybe the kill call is failing?

Answer (score 1):

You might have run into this bug: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/121

The workaround would be to downgrade supervisord until that is fixed in a released version.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the exactly same problem, downgrading to 3.0a10 solved it.